# Reading a register of nonstandard size (IDTR) in inline assembly (easy?)

Tags: c, gcc, x86, kernel, inline-assembly

I am just starting out trying to understand the linux kernel, and am trying to find the location of IDTR.  It *seems* like it should be a simple enough process, as the assembly language provides the `lidt` instruction for just this purpose.  I would think therefore, that I could provide a structure large enough to accommodate the contents of this register as an output operand, like so:

```
struct idt_ptr
{
    unsigned short limit;
    unsigned long long base;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct idt_ptr idtp;

int * get_idt() {
    __asm__
    __volatile__(
        "lidt %0;"
        : "=&r"(idtp)
    );
}
```

This doesn't work, of course.  It results in

```
/var/folders/yb/ybzqw8850nz9lzjsc6jf9hkw0000gn/T//ccvNm3SA.s:11:suffix or operands invalid for `lidt'
```

I *think* the size of the struct is correct, `short` should provide 16 bits for the segment address and `long long` 64 bits for the offset.  Is the problem simply that I can't use a struct as an output target?  How would I go about this otherwise?  Also, since resources (to my finding) have been kind of scarce, could anyone recommend a good tutorial or book on the subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [an example](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples#LIDT) of using `LIDT` in gcc inline assembly. Note that `LIDT` sets the new value of `IDTR` instead of reading the current. You should use `SIDT` to read `IDTR`. Here's an [example](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3amMssHLOJP5gJ%3awww.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ia/index.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) of how to do that in inline assembly with gcc.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple (that I confused lidt and sidt is kind of embarrassing).  It's quite clear that I was going about this backward.  Thanks for your help.